# Rename / repurpose the [coda] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The tag [coda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coda) is currently used for the code editor of the same name from the company Panic. That product [has been discontinued](https://panic.com/coda/), and it appears that the last time this tag was used for questions related to it was [almost 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862016/turn-off-the-p-symbol-in-my-code-in-coda-2).

Almost all of the recent uses of the tag have been related to the Coda document application (https://coda.io). Even Panic's own website links to coda.io at the top of their page, indicating that it is probably to correct destination for people searching for "coda".

Although questions about the Coda document application (its formula language, REST API, and Packs SDK) are still relatively rare on SO, I'd like to setup its tag for success. Would it be possible to rename the existing [coda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coda) tag to something like `[panic-coda]` so that a new [coda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coda) tag could be created for questions related to coda.io?

Comment: Since there is already precedence for a name clash, wouldn’t it be better to block the bare [tag:coda] and have "coda-topic" style tags? E.g. "coda-editor", "coda-document-api", …?

Comment: There also seem to be more uses, e.g. an R package as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746676/how-to-speed-up-read-coda

Comment: Ya, I noticed some references to an R and perhaps separate python library called "coda". In these cases is there no method for awarding the bare tag to the most popular usage? Is there a certain threshold of popularity to cross?

Comment: @EricKoleda People generally seem to pick tags only by name, disregarding the tag wiki and even popup. While you could *define* the bare tag to have a specific meaning, you cannot enforce people to adhere to or even to know it.

Comment: @EricKoleda that's a guarantee the tag will be problematic from the start with users oblivious to tag usage tagging all kinds of questions with the shortest and obvious tag. Even for an experienced user that's annoying because if you're following the tag you'll constantly be having to either retag or ignore posts.

Comment: What's the recommended path here then? Rename "coda" to "coda-panic" (or something), block the bare "coda", and create "coda.io" (or something) for the new thing? Or should we just use "coda" for coda.io questions and hope that one day we can rewrite the wiki?